# Any simple solutions for displaying photos in a related list on Lightning record page?

Tags: lightning, page-layout, related-list, images

I'm looking for an elegant solution for displaying photos in a related list in the sidebar of a record page. Similar to this screenshot, but having the photo display the full width of the sidebar, rather than just ta thumbnail.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: A quick solution would be to use this Appexchange package, https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFms7UAD

Comment: Great idea. I didn't even think to check for AppExchange packages for Lightning components. Thanks for the pointer! That one won't work because they're on Professional Edition, but there are some others compatible with Professional I can try. Thanks so much!